# Сложнейший SQL запрос

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Здравствуйте, дорогие друзья. Возник вопрос! Необходимо вычислить остаток от количества товаров на складе. Даны следующие таблицы:

**Продажи**

```
Номер        int PK
Код товара   int FK
Дата         date
Количество   int
Цена         money
```

**Поступления**

```
Номер        int PK
Код товара   int FK
Дата         date
Количество   int
Цена         money
```

**Товары**

```
Код          int PK
Название     varchar
Ед. изм.     varchar
```

Необходимо вычислить sum(Поступление.Количество) - sum(Продажи.Количество)
сгруппированых по коду товара.

**upd**:

Мое видение запроса

```
SELECT sum(col1)-sum(col2)
FROM(
        SELECT Номер, Название, Дата , Количество AS col1, Цена, Количество*Цена AS Стоимость 
        FROM Товары, Поступления
        WHERE (Код = [Код товара])
        UNION
        SELECT Номер, Название, Дата , Количество AS col2, Цена, Количество*Цена AS Стоимость 
        FROM Товары, Продажи
        WHERE (Код = [Код товара])
    )
GROUP BY Номер
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58410/discussion-on-question-by----sql-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Учитывая, что данные в этих двух таблицах по коду товара относятся друг к другу как многие ко многим и в любой из таблиц может не оказаться данных с конкретным кодом товара, то есть два пути решения. Первый, более известный:

```
SELECT coalesce(A.[Код товара],B.[Код товара]),
       coalesce(col1,0)-coalesce(col2,0)
  FROM (
        SELECT [Код товара], sum(Количество) AS col1
          FROM Поступления
         GROUP BY [Код товара]
       ) A
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT [Код товара], sum(Количество) AS col1
          FROM Продажи
         GROUP BY [Код товара]
       ) B
    ON A.[Код товара]=B.[Код товара]
```

Второй, менее известный, но часто более эффективный. И главное, работающий на всех СУБД, а не только на тех, которые поддерживают `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Заодно он практически такой, как вы привели в вопросе, по хорошему вам не хватило только понимания как сделать col1 и col2 именно отдельными колонками.

```
SELECT [Код товара], coalesce(sum(col1),0)-coalesce(sum(col2),0)
  FROM (
        SELECT [Код товара], Количество AS col1, NULL AS col2
          FROM Поступления
         UNION ALL
        SELECT [Код товара], NULL AS col1,       Количество AS col2
          FROM Продажи
       ) X
 GROUP BY [Код товара]
```

Comment: а разве если в col1 хоть одно значение из группы будет NULL, сумма не вернет `NULL`? вместо просто игнорирования

Comment: @Grundy Это вы про какой из запросов ? sum() может вернуть NULL только если всех строках был NULL. она как count() и все другм агрегатные функции NULL игнорирует

Comment: Вообще получается про оба, но возможно я что-то перепутал

Comment: @Mike а как добавить в выборку еще столбик из одной из таблиц ?

Comment: @Сергей Ну просто добавляете как обычно и все. Но все части union должны вернуть одинаковый по количеству и типам набор столбцов, так что во вторую часть, если во второй таблице нет подходящего столбца делайте NULL колонку на этом месте.

Comment: @Mike Разобрался, спасибо