# Вывести результат выборки из 2х таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

В БД есть 2 таблицы: `Куплено` и `Продано`, в которых записаны соответствующие операции, примерно так :

Столбцы: (Вид товара/Количество)

Строки : (Товар А/200 штук), (Товар А/100 штук),
 (Товар В/50 штук)

Принцип заполнения актуален и для `Продано` и для `Куплено`. В приложении нужно получить выборку : `sum(Куплено.Количество) - sum(Продано.Количество)`.

Иначе говоря из 2х таких таблиц

Куплено

[image: Куплено]

Продано

[image: Продано]

Нужно получить такую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осуществить это я пытался таким запросом:

```
SELECT sum(CountPaper)
FROM custodian.activessale
where OrderNumber = 'ES2890'
group by TitleSalePaper into @res;

SELECT Title, round((sum(PaperCount) - @res),3)
FROM custodian.activesb
where OrderNumber = 'ES2890'
group by Title;
```

Проблема в том, что более одной строки в таблице `Продано` вызывают ошибку, а если строка одна, то она и вычитается из всех строк, независимо от того, какой товар был продан. Можно, конечно, завести отдельную таблицу, и туда записывать через `Update` баланс после покупки или продажи, но если можно через запрос выводить нужное значение, то и таблицы отдельной заводить не нужно. Или вообще приложение само должно все просчитывать. Подскажите как лучше? Можно ли запросом получить корректную таблицу ?

Comment: Приведите пример таблиц на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) и результат, который хотите получить на тестовом наборе данных.

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661729/  по моему один в один как ваш вопрос, только имена колонок поправить. Смотрите сразу второй вариант решения, первый в MySQL не работает

Comment: @Mike второй тоже написан на t-sql под sql-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь (особенно @Mike и @Denis) С вашими примерами пришел к следующему коду для Mysql

```
SELECT `Title`, coalesce(sum(col1),0)-coalesce(sum(col2),0)
FROM (
    SELECT `Title`, `CountPaper` AS col1, NULL AS col2
      FROM activesb where OrderNumber = 'ES2890'
     UNION ALL
    SELECT `Title`, NULL AS col1, `CountPaper` AS col2
      FROM activessale where OrderNumber = 'ES2890'
   ) X
GROUP BY `Title`
```

где `Title` - столбец с названием товара (одинаков для обоих таблиц), 
`CountPaper` - количества товара, `OrderNumber` - фильтр (проводя аналогию с примером, который дал по ссылке @Mike это какой то отдельный магазин из сети)
ну а `activesb` - поступления и `activessale` - продажи.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал заменить NULL на ноль - тогда можно будет избавиться от COALESCE.

Comment: @Akina благодарю за совет. Я еще  не совсем разобрался в синтаксисе

Comment: @Akina не подскажите как добавлять другие столбцы в выборку ?

Comment: ДописАть их в секции SELECT...

Comment: @Akina в select который идет до FROM ?

Comment: Угу... только осторожно. Мало ли какие это поля и откуда - можно получить различные косяки, от угадайки до syntax error.

Comment: @Akina разобрался. Нужно еще и в select в выборке из ОБОИХ таблиц выбрать нужный столбец или 0(null) если в выбираемой таблице нужного столбца нет. Суть в том что бы обе таблицы возвращали одинаковое количество столбцов (или null вместо них) как я понял

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужен примерно такой запрос:

```
select b.Title,
    sum(b.PaperCount) - sum(s.CountPaper) as Title_diff
from custodian.activesb b join custodian.activessale s
    on b.Title = s.TitleSalePaper
group by b.Title
```

Comment: Поправил. Даты не имеют значения.

Comment: @Сергей обновил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы правильно меня поняли, только результат неправильный. В таблицах у меня значения как на картинке в вопросе а запрос вместо 264.00 и 639.00 выдает 23886.30 и -23166.68

Comment: Понял в чем проблема. У вас правильный код, ему просто не хватает фильтра `where`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT products.product, COALESCE(SUM(purshase.amount),0) - COALESCE(SUM(selling.amount),0) balance
FROM ( SELECT product FROM purshase
       UNION
       SELECT product FROM selling
     ) products
LEFT JOIN purshase on purshase.product = products.product 
LEFT JOIN selling  on selling.product = products.product 
GROUP BY products.product
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста код.

Comment: @Сергей берем имена продуктов из таблицы покупок и таблицы продаж (т.е. продукты могут быть только в одной из них), соединяем с продажами и с покупками снова, чтобы для каждого названия получить количество, агрегируем суммой.

Comment: @Denis Разобрался уже, спасибо.