# Объединение двух запросов в один единый

Tags: sql, oracle, birt

У меня есть два очень схожих запроса, необходимо их объединить для Dataset в BIRT. Оба запроса группируются по *b.branch*. Соответственно, необходимо, чтоб все поля с COUNT шли друг за другом как единый запрос, упорядоченные по *b.branch*.   Операторы UNION и UNION ALL не сильно помогают, либо я делаю что-то неправильно, так как, добавляю NULL-поля, то все мешается в кучу.

1 запрос:

```
select 
count(distinct(d.personid)),
count(distinct case when cvacc.thenextvac = 0  then cvacc.personid end ) as WORKERSfirstvacc,
count(distinct case when cvacc.thenextvac = 1  then cvacc.personid end ) as WORKERSsecondvacc,
count(distinct case when cmed.available = 1   then cmed.personid end ) WORKERSmed,
count(distinct case when cill.getwelldate IS NOT NULL   then cill.personid end ) WORKERSill,b.branch
from PS_Persons d     
join Ps_positions a on d.lastposid = a.positionid     
join RB_Departments b on a.Department_Code = b.Code    
join RB_Positions c on a.Position_Code = c.Code    
left join RB_Positions c2 on a.Position_Code2 = c2.Code    
left join cab_covid_ill cill on cill.personid = d.personid
left join cab_covid_medotv cmed on cmed.personid = d.personid
left join cab_covid_vacc cvacc on cvacc.personid = d.personid
where 1 = 1 and nvl(a.LEAVING_DATE, to_date('01.01.3000','DD.MM.YYYY')) > sysdate  and b.branch IN (1,224,181) and a.CONTRACTTYPE IN (1,2) and c.isteacher = 'N'
group by b.branch
```

2 запрос:

```
select b.branch, count(distinct(f.personid)) total,
count(distinct case when sf.code IN (1,3,4,6,10,11,13,14,15,16) then f.personid end) as totalzaoch,
count(distinct case when sf.code IN (2,5,12) then f.personid end) as totaloch,
count(distinct case when sf.code IN (1,3,4,6,10,11,13,14,15,16) and getwelldate IS NOT NULL then cill.personid end) as ill_zaoch,
count(distinct case when sf.code IN (2,5,12) and getwelldate IS NOT NULL then cill.personid end) as ill_ochn,
count(distinct case when sf.code IN (1,3,4,6,10,11,13,14,15,16) and cvacc.thenextvac = 0 then cvacc.personid end ) as vacc_zaoch,
count(distinct case when sf.code IN (2,5,12) and cvacc.thenextvac = 0 then cvacc.personid end ) as vacc_och
from ps_forms f     
join fc_studentrecords sr on f.personid=sr.personid  and sr.deleted=0                   
left join fc_studentsingroups sig on sig.studentid=sr.recordid     
left join fc_studentgroups sg on sg.code = sig.groupid     
left join rb_Departments b on sg.Faculty = b.Code     
left join pl_educplans ep on ep.planid=sg.planid     
left join rb_speciality sp on sp.code=ep.speccode
left join rb_StudyForms sf on ep.StudyForm = sf.Code
left join cab_covid_ill cill on cill.personid = f.personid
left join cab_covid_medotv cmed on cmed.personid = f.personid
left join cab_covid_vacc cvacc on cvacc.personid = f.personid
where (sysdate between sig.begindate and sig.enddate)     
and ((sign(AcademicYear(sysdate)-ep.YearBegin+1 - CEIL(ep.Semesters/2))<>1) and (sg.removed=0) and (sg.year_end>=AcademicYear(sysdate) or sg.year_end is null))     
and b.branch IN (1, 181, 224) and trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, f.birthdate)/12) >= 18
and ep.skillcode IN (62,65,68,90) and f.citizenship IN (1,2)
group by b.branch
```

Comment: Что означает термин "все мешается в кучу" ? NULL поля обычно ничего не портят, если есть последующий внешний group by и sum какой нибудь

Comment: кроме того можно воспользоваться full outer join этих двух запросов друг с другом

Comment: Все мешается в кучу означает, что подсчеты в count объединяются в один столбец, а мне нужно так, чтобы все столбцы были отдельно

Comment: Тогда посмотрите в сторону full outer join с ним проще будет работать. Но если идти через union, то первый запрос что то вроде `select branch, NULL as total, NULL as totalzaoch, ... и так все колонки второго запроса, count(distinct(d.personid)), пошли свои колонки`, а потом union all второго запроса в котором все наоборот `select branch, ...все свои колонки..., NULL по количеству колонок первого запроса`

Comment: Собственно вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661729/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b9-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81/661961#661961